# Bypass activate storage for android phone?

Tags: android, root

I have an android phone with broking screen that I'd like to root to eventually use it for a different purpose (as a computer).

The thing is that when I connect it to my computer it is detected, but as I recall, I have to activate access to storage on the phone before, which I can't do since the screen is broking.

Output to lsusb (on linux):
Bus 001 Device 043: ID 0bb4:0001 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)

In device manager (on win7 64bit):
[phone in the device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR0nQ.png)

(Solution on windows or linux CLI are both fine by me)

Comment: USB Debugging and Mass Storage access permissions are critical protections for protecting user data, so any method you use will be an exploit. Since you aren't yet rooted, you can't flash a new ROM or otherwise alter the system, but you may be able to use external peripherals for enabling developer mode, usb debugging, or mass storage access: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-connect-a-usb-android-keyboard/

Comment: I think this a chinese supposed to be an S6 edge, so maybe there is an exploit for it?        well the issue with the suggestion you gave, is that with no screen I won't have an idea where am going, or is there a key sequence that will solve the issue ?

Comment: I don't think you will find that kind of answer here. As for your issue, if you have enabled MTP, you may be able to access certain parts of device storage with an MTP enabled application like Windows Media Player or iTunes. Windows explorer has MTP integration in the most recent versions. Be sure to install the correct usb drivers for your android device on windows. Failing all else, if you can fastboot into a recovery shell, you MAY be able to get adb access to the device via cli or Eclipse, but that's not something I can give you blow-by-blow on.

Comment: I guess MTP is disabled, I'll try the fastboot option. Do you know where I might find a solution (other stackexchange community)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a broken one with a 4-port USB adapter (with a micro-USB to USB pigtail) for keyboard and mouse, then HDMI output.

On mine, HDMI out was a separate port, so that made it easy.

If you don't have the separate HDMI port, and depending on your model, you may be able to find a USB-to-HDMI adapter to  add to the 4-port adapter.

If you can get that far, then you can enable the mode that lets your PC access it as a media device.  Or jailbreak it for fun, whatever.

Since I considered it a throwaway otherwise, I played around with mine a lot, doing things I wouldn't do on one that I used daily.

Comment: I'll try that. I'm also thinking about 2 other possiblities : 1/ making an hdmi adapter (maybe using an FPGA to win sometime).       2/looking for a rooting solution from the hardware side, but I think this one may take too much time.